# Excel. Special number separator format for 1 specific column, no for the entire document

Tags: excel, formatting, cell

In an Excel's document, I need when you enter a positive 6 digits number (XXXXXX) into a specific cell like for example, the number **223715**, then Excel automatically format the number as **223'71'5** once you write the number into the cell and you press Enter or move to another cell, etc.

In addition to the previous explained, I need when you enter a 5 digits number, then Excel automatically adds an ending '**0**' to complete the number format to 6 digits, so if you insert the number **22589**, then Excel automatically converts it to **225'89'0**

The most important part is I need to give this "special" format **ONLY** in one single column or defined set of specific cells, because for example, I tried modifying an Excel's setting that allows to use the number separator you want but it takes effect in the entire document that is exactly what I don't need, because I need to mainly have the Excel documents in a standard way but with some columns/cells with this special format.

I tried with multiple custom Number Cell Format like "**###'##'#0.00**", "**###'##'#000'00'0**" and similar combinations trying to get positive results but no luck for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:
Try this custom format: `[<=99999]###'##'\0;###'##'#`

5 digits

[image]

6 digits

[image]

Comment: **You are a genius @Ricardo-Diaz!** I can't belive this can be done with a simple line of format, I just tried and it is exactly what I need. it is incredible!!!. I just see the answer 5 minutes ago because I'm not always in the PC, I wrote the question yesterday and I had to leave immediately, but I see you responded 4 minutes after I wrote the question. I'm in this community since this monday and I **never** **never** hadn't seen anything similar as the **lightspeed** the replies arrive here. I appreciate your ultra-fast response :)

Comment: Awesome. Please remember to mark the answer so others may find it too

Comment: Yes, of course! I just marked it as **Acepted**, my first Acepted answer. I thought to get that result was necessary a long process but seeing it can get done in this way, then below I ask you for 2 more scenarios, when you have the time to respond.

Comment: Seeing this kind of format can be setted by single custom line, I also just tried to do somthing similar with the time **hh:mm:ss** by editting the cell format as `[<=99999]##:##:##;##:##:\00` or `[<=999999]##:##:##;##:##:\00` to just type the 6 consecutive digits of a specific time and Excel automatically formats it as **hh:mm:ss** but didn't work, to even if you write 4 digits then Excel also adds the ending "00". Finally, I actually have the date with format `[$-C09]ddd\ dd-mmm-yy;@` and why not? could be great to just type 170221 and the the cell gets the format as "17-FEB-21" is possible?

Comment: Please post another question and let me know here

Comment: Sure! the additional questions are in the next new post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66247465/excel-automatic-cells-format-for-date-and-time-for-a-faster-and-simplified-wri)