# Excel. Automatic cells format for Date and Time, for a faster and simplified writing process

Tags: excel, formatting, cell

After see a cell "special" specific format can be setted in a relatively simplified way in Excel, for example, just like the post of my previous question:

[Excel. Special number separator format for 1 specific column, no for the entire document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66231734/excel-special-number-separator-format-for-1-specific-column-no-for-the-entire)

I also tried to do somthing similar like that other post with **time** data **hh:mm:ss** by editting the cell format as `[<=99999]##:##:##;##:##:\00` or `[<=999999]##:##:##;##:##:\00` to just type the 6 consecutive digits of a specific time and Excel automatically formats it as **hh:mm:ss** but it didn't work. Ideally even being possible that if you write only 4 digits, then Excel also adds the ending "**00**".

For example, if you write **135725** then to automatically get **13:57:25**, or if you write **1357** the cell automatically complete the rest as **13:57:00**, asuming that if no more final digits then is because it is "00".

In the other side, I actually have the date with the format `[$-C09]ddd\ dd-mmm-yy;@` and why not? could be great to just type **170221** and then the cell gets the format as **17-FEB-21**

Finally, I have done a brief research trying to get a site that shows how to do this kind of format but I haven't found one for formats so specific like these 2 and the other one in the link above from the other post, so I would like to know if there are any site/s where this information can be found.

Thank you

Comment: dates and times to Excel are masks on a double.  The integer part of the double is the number of days since 12/31/1899 and the decimal is the part of the day.  While you can mask `170221` as `17-02-21` with `##\-##\-##` it would not be a date.  And because it is not a date it would not be able to use the `mmm`,`dd`,`yy` codes correctly.  If you want your users to enter six digits and it to magically transform into a date that one can format it will require vba.

Comment: BTW the time mask would be: `[<=9999]##\:##\:\0\0;##\:##\:##` But again that is just a mask and would not turn the number into a true time which can be referred to.  It would just be for show.

Comment: ohhh!!! thank you @Scott-Craner for clarify those **important** details you explain. Then ideally, the way would be to "mask" a 6 digit number as a time/date format (as needed) **but** also being recognized as a time/date by Excel. In my actual specific case I need a date value be recognized as a date because the sheet makes a calculation with the date, in this case to know how many days pased from a starting date and an ending date, this actually works well, but as you say if I simply put the format as `[<=9999]##\:##\:\0\0;##\:##\:##` then it won't continue doing the calculation.

Comment: In this case you need to enter dates or use VBA as Scott said

Comment: Thank you. I've never used VBA. How can this be done in Excel to get the time and the date in the way I explain? is a long process? because it is a document in which you need to constantly enter dates and times and it could be seen as something simple but this solution can save good time that is what I'm looking for.